# How to enable GCC's GNU extensions independently of the standard?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, cmake

I want to add a C++98 / C++11 switch to a cmake-based build system. For some crossplatform-related reason it already has another switch, which is:

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "FreeBSD")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++98")
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++98")
endif()
```

So, to add C++11, I'd have to add a similar clause, and I dislike it because of code duplication. Is it really not possible to enable the extensions independently of the standard? Something like:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=${STANDARD_FLAG} ${EXTENSION_FLAGS}")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if(USE_CXX_11)
  set(CXX_VERSION 11)
else()
  set(CXX_VERSION 98)
endif()

if(USE_GNU_EXTENSIONS)
  set(CXX_DIALECT gnu)
else()
  set(CXX_DIALECT c)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=${CXX_DIALECT}++${CXX_VERSION}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the [CheckCXXCompilerFlag module](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module%3aCheckCXXCompilerFlag)?

Can be used as

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

check_cxx_compiler_flag(-std=gnu++11  HAS_FLAG_STD_GNUCXX11)

if(NOT HAS_FLAG_STD_GNUCXX11)
    check_cxx_compiler_flag(-std=c++11    HAS_FLAG_STD_CXX11)
endif()

if(HAS_FLAG_STD_GNUCXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
endif()

if(HAS_FLAG_STD_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
endif()
```

Comment: Probably because whether to use C++11 is determined by something other than compiler support for the flag. That said, this would be useful for the case where one has to fall back to 98 if 11 isn't available.

Comment: Mike is right, it has to be a user-defined switch. But this piece of information is useful too :)